# Allowing firebase storage access from another firebase app

Tags: android, firebase, storage, firebase-security, firebase-storage

I have two firebase apps. They need to access common files, so the Firebase storage is on one app. What rule should I add in Storage rules so that only these two apps get access and not anyone else? Currently I am using public setting in the rules.

Comment: Are the apps in the same project? If so, simply require authentication (which comes from a project), and you should be fine.

Comment: Oh currently I have it on different projects, I should move to the same project then

Comment: Having it in the same project is probably the easiest way, yes. One project can have multiple apps, multiple buckets, etc. while sharing authentication. Typically projects are useful for environments (production, staging, test, etc.) vs different apps (iOS, Android, web, etc. can all be in one project)